# Should we complicate aggreggate root due to an edge case?

Tags: architecture, domain-driven-design, event-sourcing, aggregateroot

Imagine that we are implementing a payment system using Event-sourcing and have events like PaymentCreated, PaymentAuthorized, PaymentSettled and PaymentInvoiced

It seems obvious that Payment should be our aggregate root, all the operations are happening on it.

But there are also refunds. A refund is basically a payment, the only difference is that it has negative amount and it has to reference a payment which we are refunding. In all other aspects it behaves like a normal payment. It has the same set of states and events, all external system handle refunds the same way as normal payments.

To make it more interesting, there can be multiple partial refunds with a constraint that sum of refund amounts has to be less or equal than the original payment amount.

We have basically two options how to implement it.

a) The payment as the aggregate root - the downside is that when checking the refund constraint we have to lock the payment we are refunding and check other refunds. In other words, refund initialization manipulates with multiple aggregate roots which is not recommended.

b) "Payment group" as the aggregate root - we can put the original payment and all of its refunds into one aggregate which can enforce the invariant. The downside is that most of the operations in the system are executed on one payment/refund level so the model does not match the use-cases. Let's say that 3rd party informs us that Payment/Refund is settled. We get an external ID, we have to find the Payment group by this ID and in there find the payment (using the same ID). It seems to unnecessarily complicate most of the code just to ensure one invariant in the refund.

What would you recommend?

Comment: I didn't get if in the option "a" you mean having the `Payment` as aggregate root with a collection of `Refund` entities. This to me seems the "simplest" solution, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Option a) means to keep Payment and Refund as separate, independent aggregates

Comment: Given your invariants I would go to have them in the same aggregate so you can guarantee data consistency, being all the data upon the same "lock", you can be sure that data doesn't end messed up, what's bad about it?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a business constraint that the refunded amount cannot go lower than the original payment amount.
2. Refunds can happen partially, so every transaction has to undergo this validation.
3. There might be multiple refunds on the way, so you need to be sure that the refund check and processing happens as part of one transaction.

Ergo, your refunds and payment are part of the same transactional consistency boundary. There should be one aggregate, `Payment`, and your `Refund`s have to be part of it. All refund transactions have to be routed via the `Payment` aggregate.

In DDD lingo, `Refund` would be an *Entity* in your domain model belonging to the `Payment` *Aggregate*.